# Yocto recipes’ dependencies

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I’m quite new to Yocto build system and I’m struggling on something I don’t understand. Actually, what’s the difference between :

DEPENDS= “foo” 
and 
DEPENDS=“foo-native”

I mean, I know the suffix -native indicates that the component foo will be built to run on the native host machine, but what are the consequences for the target machine ?

What does it change to switch a dependency to a -native dependency ?

As, in any case, everything is pre-built and pre-packaged on the host machine, where is the difference ?

Answer (score 3):

`DEPENDS` are build time dependencies which allow you to specify which packages need to exist prior to building your recipe. So `DEPENDS = "foo"` would explicity state that the **foo** package needs to be successfully built and installed ***prior*** to my package starting it's `do_configure` (it might just be a dependency for `do_compile`, but I think it's `do_configure`) process. Using a `-native` for `DEPENDS` says that packages native components need to exist as well. A good example of this is the Google **protobuf** package. It has both native and target components, and you generally need both to use it. The **protobuf-native** package would include creating the protoc compiler, which would be required to build a pacakage that needs the `protoc` compiler to generate content. It would also need the **protbuf** package for it's runtime components as well to link against.

Generally, there are no consequences so to speak. The protoc in my example above doesn't exist on the target. That answer may depend on the package though, so it's not so simple to say it has none. Generally though, use **-native** if you need a native tool to help you build a target object.